# Magento 2: Different product images in different store view

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore, store-view

I want to display different images for products for each store view. The rest of details are common for all the store views. Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this?

Comment: if you change store view in the admin im sure this allows you to set the images on a per store view basis

Comment: I tried to add different image to different view. But the image getting set to default view. All the stores getting the same image.

Comment: Did you recache

Comment: I cleaned the cache.